# Magento 2.3 Unable to override Model: Magento\Reports\Model\ResourceModel\Report\Collection

Tags: magento2, reports, resource-model, override-model

Hello I am trying to override below function in below class using `di.xml`.
Below is my code not working:

> di.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">
    <preference for="Magento\Reports\Model\ResourceModel\Report\Collection" type="Custom\Module\Model\ResourceModel\Report\Collection" />
</config>
```

Below is my model file:

```
<?php

namespace Custom\Module\Model\ResourceModel\Report;

class Collection extends \Magento\Reports\Model\ResourceModel\Report\Collection
{
    /**
     * From value
     *
     * @var \DateTime
     */
    protected $_from;

    /**
     * To value
     *
     * @var \DateTime
     */
    protected $_to;

    /**
     * Report period
     *
     * @var int
     */
    protected $_period;

    /**
     * Intervals
     *
     * @var int
     */
    protected $_intervals;

    /**
     * Intervals
     *
     * @var int
     */
    protected $_reports;

    /**
     * Page size
     *
     * @var int
     */
    protected $_pageSize;

    /**
     * Array of store ids
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $_storeIds;

    /**
     * Set the resource report collection class
     *
     * @var string
     */
    protected $_reportCollection = null;

    /**
     * @var \Magento\Framework\Stdlib\DateTime\TimezoneInterface
     */
    protected $_localeDate;

    /**
     * @var \Magento\Reports\Model\ResourceModel\Report\Collection\Factory
     */
    protected $_collectionFactory;

    /**
     * @param \Magento\Framework\Data\Collection\EntityFactory $entityFactory
     * @param \Magento\Framework\Stdlib\DateTime\TimezoneInterface $localeDate
     * @param \Magento\Reports\Model\ResourceModel\Report\Collection\Factory $collectionFactory
     */
    public function __construct(
        \Magento\Framework\Data\Collection\EntityFactory $entityFactory,
        \Magento\Framework\Stdlib\DateTime\TimezoneInterface $localeDate,
        \Magento\Reports\Model\ResourceModel\Report\Collection\Factory $collectionFactory
    ) {
        $this->_localeDate        = $localeDate;
        $this->_collectionFactory = $collectionFactory;

        parent::__construct($entityFactory);
    }

    public function getReports()
    {
        if (!$this->_reports) {
            $reports = [];
            foreach ($this->_getIntervals() as $interval) {
                $interval->setChildren($this->_getReport($interval->getStart(), $interval->getEnd()));
                if (count($interval->getChildren()) == 0) {
                    $interval->setIsEmpty(true);
                }
                $reports[] = $interval;
            }
            $this->_reports = $reports;
        }

        return $this->_reports;
    }
}
```

Comment: Did you fix this issue?

Answer (score 0):

I have the same issue fetch override another file so, You need to remove **generated, var/*** after the cache clean and check again.

Comment: did it work for you by removing generated/* ?

Comment: yes always because Magento generates dynamically.

Comment: not working....

Comment: check-in var/log file?

Comment: No logs generated either.

Comment: currently, working with developer mode?

Comment: yes developer mode, Please try with the practicle. you'll get more information about this error.

Comment: hello @DineshRajput have you found any solution ?

Comment: No. its still like 404 for me. @Hiren

Answer (score 0):

Replace Following code in your **Custom\Module\Model\ResourceModel\Report\Collection.php**

```
<?php

namespace Custom\Module\Model\ResourceModel\Report;

class Collection extends \Magento\Reports\Model\ResourceModel\Report\Collection
{
    public function __construct
    (
        \Magento\Framework\Data\Collection\EntityFactory $entityFactory,
        \Magento\Framework\Stdlib\DateTime\TimezoneInterface $localeDate,
        \Magento\Reports\Model\ResourceModel\Report\Collection\Factory $collectionFactory
    ) 
    {
        $this->_localeDate = $localeDate;
        $this->_collectionFactory = $collectionFactory;

        parent::__construct($entityFactory, $localeDate, $collectionFactory);
    }

    public function getReports()
    {
        if (!$this->_reports) {
            $reports = [];
            foreach ($this->_getIntervals() as $interval) {
                $interval->setChildren($this->_getReport($interval->getStart(), $interval->getEnd()));
                if (count($interval->getChildren()) == 0) {
                    $interval->setIsEmpty(true);
                }
                $reports[] = $interval;
            }
            $this->_reports = $reports;
        }
        return $this->_reports;
    }
}
```

You just missed following line in **__construct** function.

```
parent::__construct($entityFactory, $localeDate, $collectionFactory);
```

Comment: Yes I have also tried this way, but still facing the issue. function getReports() not calling from my custom file. it always calling from magento's module

Comment: i have checked this in fresh magento2.3.3 and its working properly, check if same class and same function is override by any other module

Comment: No other module is conflicting. can you please share screenshot so I can also get help from it.

Comment: in which grid this function is call??

Comment: admin => Reports => Product Ordered Report => Select Date ranges and click submit. If you put die('called'); in your module, then it will break the page after submit. Try to put in Magent's default file, you'll get an idea. You'll check any report, will call the function.

Comment: Its not working, instead of that can we override this function:
 protected function _getDayInterval()   ? its protected function

Comment: yes its not working, try plugin instead

Comment: Yes correct. I have also tried with plugin, still not working. I am not sure if this is a Magento2.3 latest bug. Because few days ago I have overidden Magento_Ups module, it was only worked successfully without adding __construct method. If I inject any classes or existed methods, it generates the error of missing parameters, but they are already there. Strange!!! So have to add ObjectManager method

Comment: once you find out the issue please post it here so other can use it if require

Answer (score 0):

In my case. I overwrite class
\Magento\Reports\Model\ResourceModel\Customer\Totals\Collection\Initial
You can copy function public function getReports() to this class and test